# Ignoring the collision with the tree and detect the collision with the terrain | Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently using Raycast to try to detect a collision with terrain.
I want to create an object at the same distance from the ground of terrain. Like the code below:

```
    Ray ray = new Ray(new Vector3(Random.Range(-50f, 50f), 10, Random.Range(-50f, 50f)), Vector3.down);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, (1 << 8)))
    {
        Instantiate(obj, hit.point + 10, Quaternion.identity);
    }
```

When Ray collides with terrain, it creates an object 10 higher than that.
However, if Ray hits a tree, an object will be created higher than tree.
Is there a way to ignore the tree and create an object at terrain height +10?

The layer of terrain is 8. And the layer of tree is 0 (default).
Also, I changed "Preserve Tree Prototype Layer" to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is the signature!

It is [`Physics.Raycast(Ray ray, out RaycastHit hit, float maxDistance, int layerMask, QueryTriggerInteraction queryTriggerInteraction)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)! The last three parameters have default values => They are optional and can be omitted, **but** if you provide them, they still have to be in the correct order!

You are passing in

```
Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, (1 << 8))
```

so the `1<<8` is used as the `maxDistance` and you still hit all the layers which is not what you want ;)

---

Try using

```
Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, float.MaxValue, (1 << 8))
```

---

And in general instead of doing the bitmask "manually" rather use a [`LayerMask`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) (ignore the confusing example from the API)

```
[SerializeField] private LayerMask hitMask;
```

adjust it via the Inspector and pass that one in as parameter (it is implicitly converted to `int`) ;)

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the problem was that the Raycast length wasn't specified!

Answer (score -1):

You could use the raycast mask or detect the tag. Here is a raycast with five arguments (fifth being layer).

```cs
public LayerMask layer;
RaycastHit hit;

Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out hit, 100, layer);
```

We can assign the layer through the inspector.

If we wanted to do this with tag, we could do something like:

```cs
RaycastHit hit;

Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out hit);
if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == “tree”)
{
   return;
}
else
{
    Instantiate(...);
}
```

Basically, you can get the tag or layer to filter out what you want to hit. Either of these will work.

To make what you wanted, we could do this.

```cs
Ray ray = new Ray(new Vector3(Random.Range(-50f, 50f), 10, Random.Range(-50f, 50f)), -Vector3.up);
RaycastHit hit;

Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out hit);
if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == “tree”)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    Instantiate(obj, hit.point + 10, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

(Trees have to have the “tree” tag. Comment if you don’t know how to assign tags.)

Comment: If the target of the collision is terrain, won't the tag of the tree be the same as terrain?

Comment: Good point. I didn’t know you were using terrain. I thought just game objects.